# Excel, unable to update count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to update count in the cell highlighted in red colour.
The condition is 2,  The vertical column and horizon from Agent(I13) is my condition. but I am getting it wrong please help, I want add count based on both the condition.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are getting wrong probably because of not using `Absolute Relative Reference` for Cell `I14` and just noticed you are using `Absolute Reference ` for `K13` which should be `Relative Absolute Reference` i.e. `K$13` that said the formula will be `=COUNTIFS($F:$F,$I14,$H:$H,K$13)` let me know if this not correct or not working on your end

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, Its not giving proper count. I tried as u said

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, just pasted it in the question sheet again.

Comment: See just posted, its working on my end, check answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, its working on my end:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `J14`

```
=COUNTIFS($F:$F,$I14,$H:$H,K$13)
```

---

Fill Down & Fill Right !!

---

### Edit:

If you are using **MS365** then you could play with the dynamic spill array formulas, formula credit **[JvdV Sir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `J13`

```
=LET(X,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TableOne[RCA])),
Y,UNIQUE(TableOne[Agent]),
VSTACK(HSTACK(F1,X),
HSTACK(Y,COUNTIFS(TableOne[Agent],Y,TableOne[RCA],X))))
```

---

**Note:** I have converted the range into a `Structured Table Reference` and named as **TableOne** thus excluding the non blank rows.

---